# Winforms role based security limitations

Tags: c#, winforms, roleprovider

I'm implementing role based security using Microsoft's membership and role provider.

The theoretical problem I'm having is that you implement a specific role on a method such as:

```
[PrincipalPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Supervisor")]
private void someMethod() {}
```

What if at some point down the road, I **don't** want Supervisors to access someMethod() anymore?

Wouldn't I have to change the source code to make that change? Am I missing something?

It seems there has to be some way to abstract the relationship between the supervisors role and the method so I can create a way in the application to change this coupling of role permission to method.

Any insight or direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the declarative approach, then yes - if you suddenly don't want members of the  `Supervisor` to be able to call your method, you need to change your source code for that.

You can, however, also do all of this in code, programmatically:

```
private void someMethod() 
{
    WindowsPrincipal currentUser = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as WindowsPrincipal);
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        if (currentUser.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }

}
```

You can always get the current Windows principal your Winforms app is running under, and then you can call the `IsInRole` method to check whether or not a given user is in a given role. Of course, you can also make all of this configurable, e.g. read the required role from a config file, and if you want to allow everyone in, you just simply change the role to be `Users` or something

Answer (score 5):

`PrincipalPermissionAttribute` does not tend to be used in many applications I've worked on for the reason you've touched upon; the attribute applies a policy which can only be altered by a code change.

The alternative is to use the `PrincipalPermission` class directly. All security attributes resolve to similarly named classes and method calls at run time. In the case of your attribute, the following code is executed:

```
PrincipalPermission permission = new PrincipalPermission(null, "Supervisor");
permission.Demand(); // Throws SecurityException if user is not in the role.
```

If you use the permission classes directly, you gain more control over how your permissions are formed. You could have a database which you query to get a list of roles and perform a demand for them like this:

```
private void someMethod()
{
    IEnumerable<string> roles = GetRolesForMethod("someMethod");

    PrincipalPermission permission = null;

    foreach(string role in roles)
    {
        if(permission == null)
        {
            permission = new PrincipalPermission(null, role);
        }
        else
        {
            permission = permission.Union(
                new PrincipalPermission(null, role);
                );
        }
    }

    if(permission != null)
    {
        permission.Demand();
    }
}
```